# How to use url() with offset-path in CSS

Tags: css, animation, url

I'm trying to get a svg object to follow a path.
When I use the following code, it works fine:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
    <style>
        svg {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
        }
        #arrow {
            transform-origin: center;
            transform-box: fill-box;
            animation: followPath 5s infinite;
            offset-path: path("M-54.918,380.7l285.5,0.5l0.5,354.5l173.1-0.1V480.1h181.5");
        }
        @keyframes followPath {
            0% {offset-distance: 100%;}
            100% {offset-distance: 0%;}
        }
    </style>
    <polygon id="arrow" points="574.857,479.816 585.682,473.566 596.507,467.316 596.507,479.816 596.507,492.316 585.682,486.066" />
</svg>
```

But when I try to use a path through a url, I get nothing:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
    <style>
        svg {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
        }
        #arrow {
            transform-origin: center;
            transform-box: fill-box;
            animation: followPath 5s infinite;
            offset-path: url(#guide);
        }
        @keyframes followPath {
            0% {offset-distance: 100%;}
            100% {offset-distance: 0%;}
        }
    </style>
    <path id="guide" d="M-54.918,380.7l285.5,0.5l0.5,354.5l173.1-0.1V480.1h181.5" />
    <polygon id="arrow" points="574.857,479.816 585.682,473.566 596.507,467.316 596.507,479.816 596.507,492.316 585.682,486.066" />
</svg>
```

Having to put the paths directly on the element is no good for me, i need to reference existing paths, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Support for `offset-path` is still a bit spotty (2023). I'm not aware of any browser supporting the `url()` method already. Firefox and Chrome will display `url()` as an invalid property value in dev tools. So using `path()` is currently the best way to go.

Comment: I just noticed this is still happening in Firefox v121, though MDN docs state that this should start working in v122 with "preview support": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path

Answer (score 0):

A fallback would be to put your svg in another file and then call it in your `url(..)` parameter.

```
offset-path: url("./my.svg");
```